# Wrong output in converting long strings to integer using recursive function(c++)

Tags: c++, string, recursion, int

```
    int stringToInt(string str) 
    { 

        if (str.length() == 1){ 

            return (str[0] - '0');
        }  

        double y = stringToInt(str.substr(1));  
        double x = str[0] - '0'; 

        x = x * pow(10, str.length() - 1) + y;
        return int(x); 
    }

    int main(){
        string s1= "12345";
        string s2= "123456789101";
        cout<<"s1"<<stringToInt(s1)<<endl;
        cout<<"s2"<<stringToInt(s2)<<endl;
    }
```

Correct output for s1= 12345.
But for s2= "123456789101", it gives wrong output.( negative number!!!)
Can anyone tell what is going wrong?
What should I do to convert long strings to integer using recursive function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Thanks, what should I do to convert long  strings to integer correctly?

Comment: You can't. This number is too large to fit in a 32 bit integer. You need to use a 64 bit integer.

Comment: [`std::stoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), or [`std::stoull`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul).

Comment: ***What should I do to convert long strings to integer using recursive function?*** Maybe throw an exception if the number is too large to fit into the data type you are using.

Comment: But I should convert long strings according to sample test cases of my programming homework.

Comment: Try using `long int` instead of `int`. what is `sizeof(int)` on your compiler? if it is 4 then you probably need `long int`

Comment: Also using double may cause you problems with large numbers. There are 64 bit integers that the double will not have enough precision.

Comment: You could also use one of the 64 bit types here: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer:

`123456789101 > 2147483647 = INT_MAX` (= maximum value for a variable of type `int`).

So your function is bound to return an incorrect value at some point along the way.

Replace `int` with `long long` (or even `unsigned long long`), and it might work correctly for this specific input (depending on your platform).